# Compiling OpenSSL on windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, compilation, openssl

Quoting the instructions for building OpenSSL:

> Then from the VC++ environment at a
>   prompt do:
>
> > nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

When I do this, I get

```
     cl /Fotmp32\cryptlib.obj  -Iinc32 -Itmp32 /MT /Ox /O2 /Ob2 /W3 /WX /Gs0
/GF /Gy /nologo -DOPENSSL_SYSNAME_WIN32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DL_ENDIAN -DDSO_W
IN32 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /Fdout32 -DOPENSSL_N
O_CAMELLIA -DOPENSSL_NO_SEED -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5 -DOPENSSL_NO_MDC2 -DOPENSSL_NO_CMS
 -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE -DOPENSSL_NO_CAPIENG -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -DOPENSSL_NO_DYNAMIC_
ENGINE /Zl -c .\crypto\cryptlib.c
cryptlib.c
tmp32\e_os.h(438) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No
such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN
\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Looks like I am missing setup of some environment variable that will point to where unistd.h. Not sure what it is though.

Comment: Did you run all pre-requisites commands mentioned in INSTALL file of windows? Which version of OpenSSL are you trying to compile?

Comment: Yes. I am following the steps from INSTALL.W32. 

> perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=c:/some/openssl/dir
> ms\do_ms

and it failed in the next step: nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Include\io.h` under the name `unistd.h` in the same directory and retry the build.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Common7/Tools subdirectory where Visual Studio is installed (for a typical installation C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools) for a batch file named vsvars32.bat. When you open a command prompt, run this batch file. It will define environment variables pointing to various installation directories, including where various standard header files are installed.

Comment: When I ran the bat file, it does say: "Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools." But still nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak give sthe same error.

Comment: If it made no difference, then you probably selected the option to add these environment variables to the default environment when you installed Visual Studio (it's optional, as the settings can conflict with outher development tools, but the variables must be set one way or the other for using the command line versions of the tools).

Fortunately, Mihai's suggestion seems address the specific problem with OpenSSL.